# Express $-1+i$ in exponential form.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Express $-1+i$ in exponential form.

**My attempt so far**

Let $z=-1+i$

$$r=|z|=\sqrt2$$

$$\theta=\tan^{-1}(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Now, this is where I go wrong (I don't know why it's wrong!):

So in exponential form: $-1+i=\sqrt2 e^{-i\pi/4}$

According to the solutions, $\theta=3\pi/4$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why $\theta=\tan^{-1}(-1)$?

Comment: $\tan$ is $\pi$-periodic. So taking the tangent, you lose the information in which half-plane the point lies, you have to check whether the computed angle leads to the right half-plane, otherwise correct by $\pi$.

Comment: hints: $z=\cos(\theta)+ i \sin(\theta)$ now for wich anlge you have $-cos(\theta)=sin(\theta)$?

Comment: @GitGud, because $z=x+iy$. So $\theta=\tan^{-1}(x/y)$ So, in this case, $x/y=-1$.

Comment: @MrCroutini No, mate. Given $y\neq 0$, **if** $x>0$, then $\theta=\tan^{-1}(x/y)$ and **if** $x<0$, $\theta=\tan^{-1}(x/y)+\pi$.

Comment: Gah, I think I need a diagram/image.

Comment: @Amire, Why should $-\cos(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: @MrCroutini If a picture is good enough for you, then draw one,locate the point $(-1,1)\sim -1+i$ and find the angle.

Comment: @DanielFischer Isn't $\pi/3$ in the right half plane? Top right corner?

Comment: I think I've got it! Because $(-1,1)$ is on the bottom left quadrant in the complex plane, the angle must also be in that quadrant. $\pi/3$ isn't in that quadrant, so using the fact that $\tan$ is $\pi$ periodic, correct by adding $\pi$!?

Comment: @MrCroutini $(-1,1)$ isn't in the bottom left quadrant.

Comment: @GitGud Ah yes, it's in the top left quadrant. So, the angle has to be in the same half (as in Left/Right halves) as the point on the complex plane?

Comment: Where does $\pi/3$ come from? You had $\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4}$, which in fact gives you $1-i$. The angle $-\pi/4$ points in the lower half of the right half plane. The point you're looking for is in the upper half of the left half plane, it is the negative of what you had, so you multiply with $-1$, which is adding $\pi$ to the angle.

Comment: @DanielFischer I seem to have confused myself with another question on my answer sheet. I'm really confusing myself now...

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I understand! So the angle and the point have to be in the same quadrant on the complex plane?

Comment: Well, the formulation isn't right, the angle "is" not in any quadrant, it's the ray determined by the angle that is in the quadrant, or we can say the angle "points into" the quadrant. But the idea is right.

Comment: @DanielFischer Your initial comment confused me when you said "right" half plane. You meant it as in "correct"? Now it makes sense...

Comment: Excellent, thank you for everyone's help!

Comment: @MrCroutini Indeed, "right" in that comment was used as a synonym of "correct". Unfortunate choice of word, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\tan \theta = -1$, then

- $\cos\theta > 0, \text{ and } \sin\theta <0 \implies \theta = \frac
     {3\pi}4 $,

  or else
- $\cos\theta < 0 ,\text{ and } \sin \theta > 1\implies \theta = \frac
     {7\pi}4  = -\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Since we are working with $-1 + i$, $\cos \theta \lt 0$, $\sin \theta > 0$, and hence, $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Hence, $-1 + i = \sqrt 2e^{3\pi/4}.$

Comment: Needs a TU! ... +1

Comment: @amWhy: Nope! :-) But I feel there is a match or something like a playoff game on the way. Isn't it?

Comment: @amWhy: It seems to me that you are stick to one side and are eager to see they win the title. I am watching the countdown on its page right now. I vote for Packers not 49ers.

Comment: Are your signs right?

Comment: Yup, @Jwan622 ${}{}$

Comment: Are your definitions right?

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it!
$$
-1+i=\sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{3\pi i/4}=\mathrm{e}^{\ln 2/2}\,\mathrm{e}^{3\pi i/4}=\ldots
$$

Comment: I think it's the angle that's the issue.

Comment: @GitGud: Thnx - Corrected it!

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis This doesn't help the OP, though. He doesn't understand why it should be $3\pi /4$.

Comment: How do you know it's 3pi/4

Comment: Because $\mathrm{e}^{3\pi i/4}=\cos(3\pi 4)+i\sin (3\pi /4)=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$